# How to handle duplicates with Heap's algorithm for permutations?

Tags: algorithms, permutations

I was able to use Heap's algorithm for generating permutations and I was able to solve the duplicates problem by looking at all the results and filtering out duplicates myself using a HashSet in Java.

But I was wondering if there is a way to change the code for Heap's algorithm which handles duplicates while generating them.

my code which doesn't handle duplicates ( implemented the pseudo-code mentioned on wikipedia article )

```java
    void permutationsHeapAlgorithm(int arr[]) {
        generate(arr.length, arr);
    }

    void generate(int k, int arr[]) {
        if (k == 1) {
//            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
            two += 1;
            return;
        }

        generate(k - 1, arr);

        for (int i = 0; i < k - 1; i++) {
            if (k % 2 == 0) {
                swap(arr, i, k - 1);
            } else {
                swap(arr, 0, k - 1);
            }

            generate(k - 1, arr);
        }
    }

    void swap(int arr[], int i, int j) {
        int temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = temp;
    }
```

for the input [1,1] , this code will generate [1,1] and [1,1] , ie 2 duplicates which I don't want.

Comment: Almost-duplicate of https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/119279/is-there-an-algorithm-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-multiset-through-swaps